# DNS security and port randomization

Tags: c, linux, security, dns, udp

I've been reading lately about DNS **[cache-poisoning attacks](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/iguide-kaminsky-dns-vuln.html)**.  Essentially they are possible simply because an attacker can guess the DNS message transaction ID, since it is only a 16-bit integer.  Even if the integer is random, it's still possible for a flurry of DNS packets to coincidentally match 1 of 2^16 packets in a short time window.

So a second security measure is port randomization.  If the UDP source port is random, an attacker would have to guess *both* the source port *and* the transaction ID in a short time window, which is usually not feasible.  But I read that older versions of DNS software such as BIND versions before 9 did NOT perform port randomization, and are therefore vulnerable.

This brings me to the question:  don't most UNIX OS's like Linux and BSD *automatically* assign random ports when a `SOCK_DGRAM` is used without a prior call to `bind`?  I thought that was the whole idea with ephemeral ports.  Why does an application (like BIND) have to go out of it's way to perform port randomization?

My understanding is that, essentially, an OS like Linux will have a RANGE of ephemeral ports available for use with each process.  A process can call `bind()` to bind a UDP socket to a specific port.  But if a UDP socket is used (i.e. `send` is called) without first calling `bind`, the OS will lazily assign a random ephemeral port to the socket.  So, why were older versions of BIND not performing port randomization automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This brings me to the question: don't most UNIX OS's like Linux and BSD automatically assign random ports when a SOCK_DGRAM is used without a prior call to bind? I thought that was the whole idea with ephemeral ports.

The main idea of ephemeral ports is not to be random in a secure way, but just to pick some unused port fast. Different OS use different strategies, some do it a bit random, some use a stronger random generator and some assign the ports even in a sequential way.
This means not on all OS ephemeral ports are unpredictable enough for use with DNS.

For more details I would recommend to study [RFC 6506](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6056) "Port Randomization Recommendations" and the overview about port selection strategies at https://www.cymru.com/jtk/misc/ephemeralports.html.